# How can an ActiveRecord object own 2 instances of other objects as separate properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 ActiveRecord objects:

**Location**

- id
- name
- clip_id

**Clip**

- id
- name

(in the interest of brevity - I have only listed properties relevant to this question)

and currently `clip belongs_to location` - and this works as expected.

However, my project now necessitates that `Location` needs to own 2 `clips`. One that I would like to name `listing_clip` and one that I would like to name `description_clip`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most "correct" way to model this in the database is to have a pair of foreign keys in your `locations` table, pointing to the `clips` table. To achieve this, you can invert the association, and add a `listing_clip_id` and a `description_clip_id` to your `location` table.

Then, modify your associations:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing_clip, class_name: 'Clip'
  belongs_to :description_clip, class_name: 'Clip'
end

class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :listed_location, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'listing_clip_id'
  has_one :described_location, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'description_clip_id'
end
```

Comment: Worked like a champ. Fantastic solution. Thanks!

Comment: My problem with this approach is that you will have to add a new column to the table every time you want to add another clip.

Comment: @Hamed Yes, you should have to do so. This is not a one-to-many relationship. It's a series of one-to-one relationships. Locations are not *supposed* to relate to an arbitrary number of clips.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional column to the `clips` table called `clip_type` and reference your association in the `Location` model like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :listing_clip, class_name: 'Clip', conditions: { clip_type: 'listing' }
  has_one :description_clip, class_name: 'Clip', conditions: { clip_type: 'description' }
end

class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Comment: The `clip_type` here is optional. Not a bad idea, but not needed.

Comment: @JimStewart How would you tell which clip is the listing, and which the description?

Comment: `location.listing_clip` would be whatever was assigned as the listing clip. The clip itself doesn't necessarily need to know what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

If the properties between of `listing_clip` and `description_clip` are the same (other than that name) and you don't foresee furture differences you can keep it DRY with a new column on clip called `clip_type`:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clips, limit: 2
end

class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :clip_type
  belongs_to :location
end
```